# Java substitution - multiple choices

Tags: java, regex

I need to create a single liner regex to perform substitution on job names that come from an application.

For e.g:

```
Job names                  Substituted name
---------                  -----------
PART:CP21_aserdh.2317_1    CP21
PART:XY4_gsods.2218_1      XY4
JOB:ES2                    ES2
JOB:AP50                   AP50
```

I've tried some regex which didn't work out

```
(?:(PART:(.*)_.*_)|(JOB:(.*)))
(PART:(.*)|JOB:(.*)_+)
(?:PART|JOB)[:](.*)[_]?
```

Comment: Thanks @speedogoo , the idea is helpful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the simple examples you gave, this will work:

```
str.replaceAll(".*:([^_]+).*", "$1")
```

Comment: @Marcos Why don't you upvote the answers also? :) It is cool for the answerer. PS : Does it work as expected? I tested it on Regex101 and it does not output like anubhava's answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\b(?:PART|JOB):([A-Z0-9]+).*", "$1");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qD5aT4/1)

Comment: Thanks @anubhava , it works good... but I couldn't mark ur's as answer, as there is a shorter version...

Comment: It is short because it wasn't clear in your question from your question  whether you're matching `:` after `PART` / `JOB` only or a `:` after anything. What if there are there more than one `:` in input?